# Is there any way you can parse/reformat an invalid date data in a column in Python without coercing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have this dataset with an invalid date data within a column. It is formatted `yyyymmdd` and I need them to be reformatted to `mm/dd/yyyy`. I tried coercing the value but it doesnt satisfy the conditions since it is a data and it needed to be printed out even though it is not valid.

heres a sample of the data in csv

[image: heres a sample of the data in csv]

The data have a day of '00' and we all know that day 0 is non-existent thus it produce me errors in printing the dataframe.

I tried replacing `errors='coerce` to `errors='ignore` just to see if it will push through the conditions but it doesnt.

I want to print/reformat the invalid data without coercing the value. Is there any way around?

Here is my line of code for that:

```
df['charge_off_date'] = pd.to_datetime(hals2['charge_off_date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
df['charge_off_date'] = df['charge_off_date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's invalid you cannot format it as a date imho. You can treat it as a string though and knowing that it's `yyyymmdd` format you can just format a string in a custom function and apply it to your column.

```py
def format_invalid_date(d: int)->str:
    d=str(d)
    return f"{d[:4]}/{d[4:6]}/{d[6:]}"

df['charge_off_date']=df['charge_off_date'].apply(format_invalid_date)
```

That should convert `19000100` to `1900/01/00`, which is still invalid as a date, but looks like a date format.

Comment: He said "without coercing the value". I stressed out that the "date" is invalid...Am I missing something or are you?

Comment: Hi, @Gameplay. 
This is what im trying to accomplish. I just want to treat the int as a string regardless if it is valid or not. We cant change the value of data for this instance.

However, i tried your script but it gives me  this error:

return f"{d[:4]}/{d[4:6]}/{d[6:]}"
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Kevi Done, gotta cast to string explicitly first

Comment: @Gameplay nice! it works. Thanks. I gotta study on how this script works.

Comment: Happy to help. I'd recommend pandas docs on `apply`. What it does is, shortly speaking, takes each element of the column ( in this case, can be a whole dataframe as well) and applies the defined function. A bit similar to what `map` does in python (without pandas).